# Jupyter notebook: How to \xlongequal for LaTeX

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4m6F.png)
I'm a new to jupyter,I typed a determinant calculation.

My problem is why the Longequal can not be displayed.

Can you give me some suggestion？

Thanks in advance.

Sorry I am Chinese.My English is poor.T.T

Comment: Have a look if https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/extpfeil.html helps

Comment: Thanks ,I have tried But the `\Newextarrow` can't run and displayed too.

Comment: No, you don't want to create a *new* arrow, you want to load the extension, e.g. `\require{extpfeil}` in your math expression.